# A dialog that allows a single selection in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to create a list dialog that will only allowed a single selection from a list of options `ListSelectionDialog` seems like a good option, but I could not find a way to restrict it to a single option, or change it to radio buttons.

I read the followings, and could not find any indication on how to do so:
https://dzone.com/articles/discover-eclipses-jface-dialog

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fdialogs%2Fpackage-summary.html

Comment: For radio buttons you would have to write your own dialog extending `SelectionDialog` (or even just the JFace `Dialog`).

Comment: can one limit the checkboxes in ListSelectionDialog  to a single selection?

Comment: Is [JOptionPane.showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) not sufficient?

Comment: @VGR this will allow the user to supply input, I want to restrict the user to select one option from a supplied list

Comment: Actually, the seven-argument JOptionPane.showInputDialog does not allow arbitrary input.  The dialog contains a non-editable JComboBox from which the user must select exactly one option.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a class derived from `ListSelectionDialog` you can call the `getViewer()` method to get the `CheckboxTableViewer` the dialog uses.

You could then add a check state listener to force a single selection:

```java
CheckboxTableViewer viewer = getViewer();
viewer.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
  @Override
  public void checkStateChanged(final CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
    viewer.setCheckedElements(new Object[] { event.getElement() });
  }
});
```

Although I think this might confuse users expecting a checkbox list to support multiple selection.

Comment: I agree with you that UI-wise this is a bad idea, I am looking into creating my own selection dialog, trying to read the java docs and understand what is needed.

could not find any useful examples at the moment, so for now it is a trail and error